# how long to wait for re-painting one side of fence after pressure washing the otherside which is unpainted

Tags: painting, pressure-washer

It hasn't rained much this summer, and not any in a week. Today, I've prepped (sanded, brushed off, wiped down with a damp sponge) the painted side of a 1x6 cedar privacy fence, which was last painted a couple years ago. Then I used a homeowner-class pressure washer to clean the other side, which is untreated/unpainted roughsawn ceder. Can the painted side be repainted now with latex paint (not stain)? I say yes. Wife says no.

Edit: I think I answered my own question. It is a matter of new paint bonding to old paint. The old paint would be sealing off this bond from any moisture from the pressure washing of the otherside that would over the next week/month raise the moisture content of the wood just under the old paint.  She agrees.  She treats tonight !

Comment: Do you intend to paint it "often"? Multiple coats of latex paint? Is this pressure treated wood? Is the fence older than 2 years? Where do you live (climate)

Comment: Cool, so they make pressure treated cedar?

Comment: I failed to read that part! And apparently a few others. It happens.. Did it say cedar before? :) man.......

Comment: If you answered your own question than enter it as an answer and accept it. The community will vote it up or down depending on what the community at large thinks of your answer.

Comment: I'd wait a week, but am paranoid about these things. Used to enjoy popping the paint bubbles on the neighbors house when I was a kid. Probably not a problem now days.

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that latex paint bonds well to damp wood. I think you should have no problem with painting now

Comment: if it is pressure treated and he is not staining it, he should prime before painting. Also, I am under the opposite understanding, do not paint wet wood. Does it have to be perfectly dry? No. But seasoned and dry is good to avoid moisture being trapped inside causing eventual peeling/bubbling. From his write up it sounds "dry enough"

Comment: @Jim Stewart - Isn't a matter of new paint bonding to old paint ?

Comment: I suspect we, (or at least I... perhaps Jim was being sarcastic), thought you intended to paint the whole thing. As long as the surface of the painted surface is dry, *and clean, you can repaint it now. But you should let the untreated part dry first, and since you are bound to get paint on wet wood, probably just wait a few weeks and if the weather is nice, have a weekend paint party. make it a family affair :)

Answer (score 1):

You are overthinking this. Go ahead and paint the previously painted side, no need to prime.